# Spring MVC - Multipart Upload Image return null

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, multipart

i'm using Spring MVC and Multipart to upload the image. But it always return null. I've setup all the configuration and until now i could not figure out the reason. Anyone who had this kind of experienced please help me. Thank you so much.

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>    
</dependency>   
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>  
</dependency>
```

bean xml

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
       <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="167772160" />
    </beans:bean>
```

@Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data/edit/request", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = Constant.MULTIDATA_CHARSET_UTF_8)
    public String updateData(Model model, HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs,
            @ModelAttribute RawUserDto rawUserDto) {    
        try {
            int rawUserSn = userService.insertRawUser(rawUserDto.toRawUser());
            if(rawUserSn > 0){//insert new raw users
                //to-do
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Write log and redirect to error page
            LOG.error(e);
        }
        return "inputData";
    }
```

RawUserDto

```
public class RawUserDto implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String birthday;

    private int gender;

    @JsonIgnore
    private MultipartFile avatar;
}
```

JSP file

```
<form:form  class="form-horizontal" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/data/edit/request" method="POST" role="form" modelAttribute="rawUserDto" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Avatar <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <form:input type="file" path="avatar" name="avatar" class="file-styled" required="required" accept="jpg;gif;png;bmp;jpeg"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

For more information you can see the image attached which is i captured from my screen. As you can see that others information i can get it only the multipart data is NULL.

[Debug mode by screen captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQpsG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

saving image

```
public void createProduct(User user, MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
String rootDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/webapp/static/images/items";
    for (MultipartFile file : files){

        Path path = Paths.get(rootDir, file.getOriginalFilename());
        String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();

        try{

            Files.write(path, file.getBytes());

        }catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            throw new MultipartException("You got an Error men");

        }

        user.setAvatar(filename);

    }
    rawUserDtoRepository.save(user);

}
```

public class RawUserDto implements java.io.Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String name;

private String email;

private String birthday;

private int gender;

@JsonIgnore
private String avatar;
```

}

save the image file in the static folder, just like a js css

Comment: Hi @viray, where did you put this function (createProduct) in the source code and did you  use ModelAttribute for get multipart file ?